# What should I use for my model?

Tags: ember.js

I have a template which works with this model structure:

```
App.BuildingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      imgSrc: 'img/Images/44.png',
      name: 'name',
      addr1: 'Address Line 1',
      addr2: 'Address Line 2'
    }
  }
}
```

But I need this data to be up-date-able and coming from our server. So I tried this:

```
App.BuildingData = DS.Model.extend({
  imgSrc: 'img/Images/44.png',
  name: 'name',
  addr1: 'Address Line 1',
  addr2: 'Address Line 2'
});

App.BuildingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var store = this.get('store');
    var stuff = store.find('BuildingData');

    return stuff;
  }
}
```

Which I get a bunch of errors for. Is there a simple example somewhere of how to have a model which can be updated by a function somewhere else in the program?

I have a function `getNodeInfo()` which gets data from our server and returns something like this:

```
{
  imgSrc: 'img/Images/44.png',
  name: 'name',
  addr1: 'Address Line 1',
  addr2: 'Address Line 2'
}
```

Where am I supposed to call `getNodeInfo()` from, I had it inside the model function, but that got errors as well.

I dont even know if i need to use ember-data, maybe Ember.Object would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use ember data (until it final) so you can use basic javascript variable or array to serve you as a model. But you should put that variable in global context so just try to do like this:

```
var imageModel = {
  imgSrc: 'img/Images/44.png',
  name: 'name',
  addr1: 'Address Line 1',
  addr2: 'Address Line 2'
};

App.BuildingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
     return imageModel;
}};
```

Remember to use Ember API to modify model's properties like this:

```
Ember.set(imageModel,'name','hereIsTheNewName');
```

So Ember will update everywhere on views.

If you want to fetch data from server then use jQuery.ajax call:

```
App.BuildingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
     return $.get('/your/app/url').then(function(data){
         //suppose your server returns JSON
         imageModel = data;
         return imageModel;
     });
}};
```

So what it shows? Ember can operate with javascript promise objects!

Comment: How might I set multiple properties at once?

Comment: Also, is $.get('/your/app/url') supposed to return data?

Comment: Yes it must return JSON response

Answer (score 0):

Didar's solution works, but if you want to make use of Ember's LoadingRoute and eliminating unnecessary global variable, here it is:

```
App.BuildingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
       return Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
           $.getJSON('/app/url', function(data) {
               resolve(Ember.Object.create(data));
           });
       });
   }
});
```

Want to change properties? Just get the model in your route or controller.

```
this.get('model').set('name', 'My New Name');
```

Comment: What if other routes or controllers use same object?

Comment: Resolve is the function to let ember know that the data has been loaded successfully. If we don't call resolve(), Ember will wait forever.

Comment: But where is located "resolve" ? Ember.resolve doesn't exist and resolve also do not exist, so it implies that it is your's custom function, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is. Please see here for further information, since Ember's RSVP is implemented from it: https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/blob/master/README.md